# Can the phrases "is equal to" and "equals" be used interchangeably?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, definition

**I found a duplicate to this question in the English StackExchange.**
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71259/is-equal-to-or-equals

I see these two phrases a lot in the context of mathematics. They seem interchangeable, but I cannot be sure, because I'm not well acquainted with English or maths. Do you think they
are interchangeable? If not, in what circumstances do you prefer one to the other?

Comment: are $2$ **equals** $2$ and $2$ **is equal to** $2$ same?

Comment: @Algebrology Yes, I think so, but I would still very much like to hear from other people!

Comment: Actually both of them are same and convey the same thing. And you answered your own question

Comment: @Algebrology Well, thank you for letting me know that. I wasn't sure if I was right.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3):

They are *almost* interchangeable; however, arguably, [there are no true synonyms in natural language](https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2015/11/25/there-is-no-such-thing-as-a-true-synonym-in-english-discuss/). Aside from a subtle change in [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28sociolinguistics%29), there are specific contexts where one or the other sounds more natural to me, or where one is more ambiguous than the other.

For instance, "[equals sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equals_sign)" is common across many countries with a large English-speaking population. But [Google Trends suggests](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=%22Equals%20sign%22,%22Is%20equal%20to%20sign%22) that "is equal to sign" seems to only have significant use in India, if anywhere.

On the other hand, consider "is-equal-to [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29)" (sometimes with quotation marks around 'is equal to' instead of hyphens). That phrase is always used to mean the particular [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) $R$ given by "$aRb$ [exactly when](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) $a=b$". But at least [one scientific dictionary*](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/equals+relation) defined "equals relation" as "equivalence relation", in general. So there is, at best, more ambiguity with "equals relation". Personally, I don't think I have ever heard "equals relation".

*McGraw-Hill Dictionary of Scientific & Technical Terms, 6E

Comment: Right. The question was intended for when I want to say something is equal to something, but that is a valid point too; there are many other circumstances where "is equal to" or "equals" are used. I appreciate the useful links too. Thank you.